# Adding a response header to S3 bucket calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, security, amazon-s3, header

I have a s3 bucket that I created and I am adding objects and reading them in a client that calls the bucket via `my_bucket.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` endpoint. Is there any way to add a header (eg: `Strict-Transport-Security`) to the responses from S3 (using aws console or cloudformation).

I am aware that I can do this by using cloudfront to route the request. But I want to know if I can achieve this directly from S3.

Comment: I think the closest solution is an S3 bucket policy that denies non SSL requests [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-policy-for-config-rule/).